# "IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable" with PhantomJS, python, selenium, unittest

Tags: python, macos, selenium, phantomjs, python-unittest

I'm having an issue with running unit tests using `selenium` and the PhantomJS driver.  It seems to be related to resource contention for stderr/stdout in the PhantomJS process.  The error is:

```
$ python -m unittest selenium_failure.SeleniumTestCase
[]
[{u'timestamp': 1395857498698, u'message': u'{"log":{"version":"1.2","creator":{"name":"PhantomJS","version":"1.9.7"},"pages":[{"startedDateTime":"2014-03-26T18:11:38.347Z","id":"https://www.google.com/","title":"Google","pageTimings":{"onLoad":294}}],"entries":[{"startedDateTime":"2014-03-26T18:11:38.344Z","time":127,"request":{"method":"GET","url":"https://www.google.com/","httpVersion":"HTTP/1.1","cookies":[],"headers":[{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34"},{"name":"Accept","value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"}],"queryString":[],"headersSize":-1,"bodySize":-1},"response":{"status":200,"statusText":"OK","httpVersion":"HTTP/1.1","cookies":[],"headers":[{"name":"Date","value":"Wed, 26 Mar 2014 18:11:37 GMT"},{"name":"Expires","value":"-1"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"private, max-age=0"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html; charset=UTF-8"},{"name":"Set-Cookie",E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_that_something_fails (selenium_failure.SeleniumTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_failure.py", line 16, in test_that_something_fails
    print repr(self.selenium.get_log('har'))
IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.398s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

More detailed gist here: https://gist.github.com/lucaswiman/9788422

```
import unittest
import logging
from selenium.webdriver import phantomjs
import sys

class SeleniumTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.selenium = phantomjs.webdriver.WebDriver()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.quit()
    def test_that_something_fails(self):
        self.selenium.get('https://www.google.com')
        print repr(self.selenium.get_log('browser'))
        print repr(self.selenium.get_log('har'))
        raise AssertionError()
```

The error is reproducible with that gist on OS X, but not on Ubuntu 12.04.  I believe it's not specific to OS X, since I've seen a similar error for our integration tests on running on Ubuntu, though I haven't been able to reproduce it in an isolated form.

- Python 2.7.6
- selenium==2.35.0
- phantomjs@1.9.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!  A coworker pointed me to this related issue: http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2066#comment:1  I modified the patch there to make `sys.__stderr__` and `sys.__stdout__` have the block flag.  Calling that function immediately after the instantiation of the phantomjs `WebDriver` allowed the stderr to be sent to stderr.