# Selenium Phantomjs browsers hangs on startup. How do I debug it?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to help run my selenium (Python bindings version 2) tests on someone else setup.

It works with the Firefox esr(on both machines), it works with the latest phantomjs on my machine. It hangs on his machine.

Only obvious difference between is he's on Windows 10 and I'm on Windows 7. I don't think it's the firewall or proxy cause I took care of it ( enabling everything for the firewall and running it with `--proxy-type=none`).

How do I debug it?

Comment: This question should provide steps to reproduce the problem, including code. Why? Because the strategies used for debugging depend on the specifics of what you are trying to do. And "hangs on startup" is a pretty vague description.

Comment: I don't know much about windows, but on Unix systems, selenium and phantomjs do some changes to the stderr and stdout IO modes, so it could be that it's somehow deadlocking an IO stream. This issue I ran into might be relevant reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669734/ioerror-errno-35-resource-temporarily-unavailable-with-phantomjs-python-s

Answer (score 0):

More details could help. Do you get an error message? How is your code?

In any case, some ideas that may help to figure out what is happening are:

Set the window size to something appropriate for your tests.

```
driver.set_window_size(900, 800)
```

Save screenshots.

```
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

Check if the page source matches your expectations.

```
with open('temp.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

You may try to see if upgrading Selenium helps.

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

You may test [other versions of PhantomJS](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads), by downloading and specifying the path. Version 1.9.8 helped me with bypassing some security restrictions in the past.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
    executable_path='/path/to/the/downloaded/phantomjs19',
    # you can specify args, such as:
    service_args=[
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=true', 
        '--ssl-protocol=any', 
        '--web-security=false',
    ],
    # and also other capabilities:
    desired_capabilities={
        'phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout': '5000',
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent': (
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
            "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
        ),
    },
)
```

Please, let me know if this helps!