# Selenium webdriver robot running in a javascript rendered website

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I have a robot getting data from a javascript rendered website which is working perfectly with Chrome webdriver. However I wish to run this robot as a background job without any display.

I've tried PhantomJs, but it is not working properly. I guess it is not supporting some javascript rendering from this website.

Someone has any other guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listed some basic ideas to figure out problems when using PhantomJS on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173098/1204332). Maybe try those ideas to see if you can get it working for you.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I followed your suggestions. I've got a screenshot and I noticed that the window's width was too small and I set it larger. As the website is resposive, some elements are different in the mobile size. Now it is working finel! Thanks a lot.. I own u a beer! Cheers!